# How can i turn of this Function?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi i have a Question how is this element called?
[(White Arrows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uaA4.jpg)
I used this element to close my code blocks, but
every time i interact with the code it Pops-open!
I want it to stay closed is there a way to configure that in settings?
[thats how its supposed to stay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn7W3.jpg)

every time i interact with the code this happens:
[it opens from its self why and can i change?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD65I.jpg)

Comment: read the doc on **Folding**, search the keybindings for `fold`

Comment: search the keybindings fold okay, but how do i find the doc? Is it in VS-Code?

Comment: there are a finite number of doc pages, many you do not have to look at (the title says enough like **Remote**) all pages have a TOC so very easy to screen if the topic you look for is on that page

Comment: but excuse me, what did u mean with: read "the" doc? Why did u say the? Did u think about a particular doc?

Comment: VSC has a large number of manual/documentation pages, one of these pages talks about Folding.

Answer (score 0):

That's feature called Folding. It's a toggle. So, if you fold a section, it will be unfolded when you click the button again. You can read the completed guide here (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding)

Comment: Alright, the link from u was very helpful, but still couldn't figure out why the section unfolds even if i didn't click the toggle button.